# SQL query to get 2nd last row

Tags: sql

I have a sql table named User. I want to sort it by id and get the second last user. Is there a generic way to do that in sql?

For example I have these rows:

```
id    name
1     User 1
2     User 2
3     User 3
4     User 4
```

I want to write a sql query to get User 3. I want a generic query that I can use for the 3rd last or 4th last user as well.

Comment: Only tag the *one* DBMS you're really using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query below will get you the second to last user based on the id. It achieves this by first ordering by `id` in descending order, using the `OFFSET 1` to skip the new first row in the order i.e. `User 4` and the `LIMIT 1` to get just `User 3` the next remaining user. The general pattern as shown in the fiddle which you can run online is to update the `OFFSET`

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE User (
  `id` INTEGER,
  `name` VARCHAR(6)
);

INSERT INTO User
  (`id`, `name`)
VALUES
  ('1', 'User 1'),
  ('2', 'User 2'),
  ('3', 'User 3'),
  ('4', 'User 4');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT "GET 2nd to Last";
```

| GET 2nd to Last |
| --- |
| GET 2nd to Last |

---

**Query #2**

```
SELECT
    *
FROM 
   User
ORDER BY
   id desc
LIMIT 1
OFFSET 1;
```

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | User 3 |

---

**Query #3**

```
SELECT "GET 3rd to Last";
```

| GET 3rd to Last |
| --- |
| GET 3rd to Last |

---

**Query #4**

```
SELECT
    *
FROM 
   User
ORDER BY
   id desc
LIMIT 1
OFFSET 2;
```

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | User 2 |

---

**Query #5**

```
SELECT "GET 4th to Last";
```

| GET 4th to Last |
| --- |
| GET 4th to Last |

---

**Query #6**

```
SELECT
    *
FROM 
   User
ORDER BY
   id desc
LIMIT 1
OFFSET 3;
```

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | User 1 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/)

Answer (score 2):

Alternate solution easy to understand solution:

You can replace the `LIMIT 2` in the nested query with `LIMIT 3` to get the 3rd to last or `LIMIT 4` to get the 4th to last user.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
 SELECT *
 FROM User
 ORDER BY id DESC
 LIMIT 2
)
ORDER BY id
LIMIT 1
```